# How to prevent the enter key from triggering a click event when a button is in focus

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, enter, keycode

I'm trying to make a program which can accept button based inputs as well as keyboard based inputs which it then outputs to a text box. However I would like to use the Enter key to trigger the function to output to the text box. However since there are buttons on the form. They will be triggered like a mouse click event when the enter key is pressed. I need to find a way to either make the enter key only trigger the event I want and not to trigger the button. Or I need to find a way to make the buttons never have focus and for the focus always to be on the form itself while still having the buttons be clickable. Any help?

```
       If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        SecondNum = Val(TB_Output.Text)
        ResultEquals()
        TB_Output.Text = Result
    End If
```

Comment: Check out the `KeyPreview` property on the `System.Windows.Form` class.

Comment: The Space key operates the button with the focus.  The Enter key does something completely different, it operates the button you've selected as the default Accept key.  Typically the OK button.  If you're already confused by your own UI then your user doesn't stand much of chance either, maybe changing it isn't such a good idea...

Comment: @HansPassant: I tested this, it seems like both enter and space operate equally on the button in focus, namely pressing the button. Tried in different ways, no difference. So which setup are you referring to, in which it would work the way you described above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically, setting `KeyPreview` property of the form to `True` should do it. Then handle `KeyDown` event, and make sure to set `e.Handled` to `True` on pressing the Enter key (or e.[SuppressKeyPress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.suppresskeypress%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), depends on implementation of controls you are working with).

I tried this approach in a sample project just now, however, and it did not work with a button for some reason. You may need to resort to using `WndProc` on the form level, this always works 100%.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go right to the heart of the key events, and intercept even the arrows and other focus-changing keys, you'll need something like this:

```
Protected Overrides Function ProcessDialogKey(ByVal keyData As System.Windows.Forms.Keys) As Boolean
        Select Case keyData
            Case Keys.Enter
                'your logic here
                Return True  'this surpresses any default action
        End Select
        Return MyBase.ProcessDialogKey(keyData) 'this allows the default action to be processed for any cases you haven't explicitly intercepted

    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Attach your button callback to the `MouseClick` event instead of the `Click` event.  Enter and space keys will still raise the Click event, but your code will only run when the user actually clicks with the mouse.